# Python DataFrame shape difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

for dataframe with shape (143, ) and (143, 1)

Are they the same? they are all 1-column dataframe with 143 rows.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the first object is actually a `pd.Series` object, while the latter is a `pd.DataFrame` object with a single column.

You can understand by observing a sample here:

```
df

    A   B
0   3   5
1   1   4
2   4  10
3   0  17
4  13   4
5  12   6
6   3   9
7   3   9
8   7   4
9   1   6

df['A']

0     3
1     1
2     4
3     0
4    13
5    12
6     3
7     3
8     7
9     1
Name: A, dtype: int64

df['A'].shape
(10,)

type(df['A'])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

```
df[['A']]

    A
0   3
1   1
2   4
3   0
4  13
5  12
6   3
7   3
8   7
9   1

df[['A']].shape
(10, 1)

type(df[['A']])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Note here that the double `[[..]]` notation is used to extract dataframe sub-slices from a larger dataframe.

---

If you have a series and want to convert it into a dataframe, you can use `to_frame`:

```
s = df['A']

type(s)
pandas.core.series.Series

v = s.to_frame()
v

    A
0   3
1   1
2   4
3   0
4  13
5  12
6   3
7   3
8   7
9   1

type(v)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as dataframe with shape (143,)
a data frame is 2D, even if it has no columns or one column

```
pandas.DataFrame(index=range(10)).shape
(10, 0)

pandas.DataFrame(index=range(10), columns=[0]).shape
(10, 1)
```

a pandas Series is a one dimensional object:

```
pandas.Series(range(10)).shape
(10,)
```

Comment: You are right if he `shape` mean `DataFrame` property!

Comment: @FengGuo If you have a new question, would you consider writing a new post please?